# WordPress plugin with e-mail mass sending

Tags: php, wordpress, email, cron

I'm currently making a promotion plugin for WordPress where I need to send out e-mails to different press e-mails based on a checkbox-list. My hosting provider has a limit of 200 e-mails/hour, but I don't think I will reach that limit. I know that mailing list providers are recommended, but my plugin has some functions (like making promo codes etc.). Everything is now finished with the plugin, and I only need the function for sending.

I have been searching for solutions, and have been looking at timers in PHP to avoid spam detection. I think I will end up with Cron jobs. I have looked into the built in WordPress cron job function, and will try to use this one.

I have never been using cron jobs before, so my questions is: how can I keep track on which e-mail my plugin has sent to? Do I need a temp table where each row is deleted when sent?

Any other suggestions for my solution would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(mail(//params))
{
    //insert this email id in db
}
```

you can keep track by inserting email id in to db if email sent successfully.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better do add all e-mails in a temp table when the user click 'send'? And then in the cron job check if mail address is in temp table, and remove it after it was sent?

Comment: but what about future records, if you want to know how many email you had sent and their email address then

Comment: Good point! I was actually planning to just update the record in the e-mail table, but then the plugin would only work for one send out. Your solution sounds good! Thanks!

Comment: if you find my solution good please don't forgot to use your valuable upvote

Comment: Will do. But one more thing. I still need a temp table to know which it will send to as well, right?

Comment: Figured I only need one table to handle it. In the table I have campaign/newsletter #, recepient # and sent = 0, and I update sent with 1 in the cron job.